# Connect Signalr Hub and Client using different IP address

Tags: signalr

Working in VS 2019.

Im new to SignalR, I have written Hub/Client apps which I cannot get working over my local home LAN using two PC's on different IP's.

So I went back to basics and loaded the sample chat apps but I have the same problem.

Im using the Demo Chat samples from github [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples)

PC A (my work PC) working as a SignalR Hub running the Chat Hub (192.168.0.2).

PC B (my Laptop) running the Chat 'Windows Forms Sample' Client (192.168.0.9)

Firewalls: I have allowed both Inbound and Outbound  Rules for port 52995 on both PC's.

The Hub connection:

```
string ip = "localhost";
string port = "52995";

var url = new Uri($"http://{ip}:{port}/chat");

App.HubConn = new HubConnectionBuilder()
           .WithUrl(url, options =>
           {                   
           })
           .Build();
```

If I run the Winforms client on the same PC as the Hub (localhost) then all is ok, but on the Laptop the **error** I get is:

```
System.Net.HttpRequestException. Response code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)
```

For clarity the Winforms chat client app allows you to enter the url in a textbox:

```
http://localhost:52995/chat   ----> client running on localhost   -> works
http://192.168.0.2:52995/chat ----> client running on 192.168.0.9 -> error
```

I have been trying to resolve this for over a day now, why wont this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

My use case is a bit different.

I need to run the server hub on a windows 10 PC with a no more that a dozen or so local (LAN) clients (so its all local LAN, no cloud) .  Kestral seems to be the server to use in this case.

I learned **IIS Express** only handles **localhost** traffic.

For testing I was running a copy of Visual Studio in a VitrualBox vm (for the server hub) this meant VS was using IIS Express and therefore no traffic outside of localhost allowed & therefore the 400.

**To get it to work**

Use the CLI to start the web app - this will use Kestral as the **sole** web server (normally IIS proxies http traffic to/from Kestral)

```
dontnet run <your app name>
```

I also set the Hosting Model to OutOfProcess (in csproj)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OuOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Although im not certain this actually made any difference as it seems dotnet run works in this hosting mode.